# I have searched for code translators and can find no comprehensible answer. I need to know what this bit of python codes means

Tags: python, translation

```
1   first_num = raw_input("Please input first number: ")
2   sec_num = raw_input("Please input second number: ")
3
4   answer = int(first_num) + int(sec_num)
5
6   print "Now I will add your two numbers: ", answer
7
8   print "Pretty cool, huh?"
9
10  print "Now I'll count backwards from ", answer
11
12  counter = answer
13
14  while (counter >= 0):
15      print counter
16      counter = counter - 1
17
18  print "All done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does roughly what the print messages say it does.  It takes two numbers, adds them together, and then prints a counter from the sum down to 0.

```
Please input first number: 2
Please input second number: 3
Now I will add your two numbers: 5
Pretty cool, huh?
Now I'll count backwards from 5
5
4
3
2
1
0
All done!
```